# openpyxl delete_rows function is not deleting rows

Tags: python-3.x, openpyxl

Am using openpyxl version2.4.1. Using `ws.delete_rows(i)` to delete rows.
But its throwing an exception **"AttributeError: 'Worksheet' object has no attribute 'delete_rows'"**

Can somebody help on this?

Answer (score 0):

Version 2.4.x does not have the `delete_rows` method - You can confirm this by checking for `delete_rows` in the output of `dir(ws)` (Assuming `ws` is your worksheet object)

Comment: Hi Mortz, Thank you for your prompt response. True its v2.4.1 does not have delete_rows function. Can you please suggest what is the equivalent function?

Comment: Not too sure - you can try searching for it in the documentation [here](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/2.4/index.html)